# Image sensor response data

Tags: data-request

I am in need of data about the **quantum efficiency** across all wavelengths (visible and UV if possible) for image sensors used in smartphones (CMOS).

Comment: Usually supplied by vendors.

Answer (score 1):

[This PDF](http://ghgtechn.com/admin/upload/634912822373126250MT9M034_DS_B.pdf) contains a graph showing the quantum efficiency across all wavelengths from 380 nm to 1050 nm:

[image: CMOS quantum efficiency]

Notes:

- Data is for the MT9M034 1/3-Inch CMOS Digital Image Sensor
- It is a graph, so values have to be sampled from it, and precision is not great
- It is not open data